# Set the focus to a specific datagrid cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, focus, cell

I am trying to set the focus of a cell in a datagrid based on a entered part number so the user can barcode scan the part and then edit the value very quickly. Now, I can find the index of the part number in the ObservableCollection of items I have but I am having trouble trying to set it to that grid cell. grTimeEntries is the name of the data grid. The current code below gives me an error when trying to create the new DataGridCellInfo

```
Error   1   Cannot initialize type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellInfo' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'
```

The code:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ToFind = tbIPN.Text;
        for (int i = 0; i < (grMain.DataContext as DatabaseViewmodel).items.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((grMain.DataContext as DatabaseViewmodel).items[i].IPN == ToFind)
            {
                grTimeEntries.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo { grTimeEntries.Items[i], grTimeEntries.Columns[1] };
                //grTimeEntries.SelectedIndex = i;          Focussed entire row. Wont work if i have selectionunit = "Cell".
                grTimeEntries.Focus();

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a dependency property to focus the cell will work for you.

```
    public class EDataGridCellFocus
{
    public static object GetFocusedCell(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return obj.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetFocusedCell(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
         "FocusedCell", typeof(object), typeof(EDataGridCellFocus),
         new UIPropertyMetadata(false, null, OnCoerceValue));

    private static object OnCoerceValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        if (((DataGrid)d).Items.Count > 0 || ((DataGrid)d).HasItems)
        { 
            var row = ((DataGrid)d).ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(baseValue[0]) as DataGridRow;
            if (row != null)
            {
                var cell = ((DataGrid)d).GetCell(row, baseValue[1]);

                    Keyboard.ClearFocus();
                    FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(d, true);
                    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(cell, cell);
                    Keyboard.Focus(cell);                    
            }
        }
        return baseValue;
    }
}

 public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, DataGridRow row, int columnIndex = 0)
    {
        if (row == null) return null;

        var presenter = row.FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>();
        if (presenter == null) return null;

        var cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(columnIndex);
        if (cell != null) return cell;

        // now try to bring into view and retreive the cell
        grid.ScrollIntoView(row, grid.Columns[columnIndex]);
        cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(columnIndex);

        return cell;
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(this DependencyObject depObj)
   where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(this DependencyObject obj)
        where childItem : DependencyObject
    {
        foreach (childItem child in FindVisualChildren<childItem>(obj))
        {
            return child;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

set your XAML like below,

```
<DataGrid EDataGridCellFocus.FocusedCell="{Binding Cell}"/>
```

Binding Property

```
public Object[] Cell
{
   get;
   set;
}
```